Cortex M0+ Starts Throwing Hard Fault When Assigning Value to a Particular Typedef'd Struct
Strange issue I’m stumped on: have some code I’ve been working on for months with no issues (well, not this issue). But suddenly, the assignment of a value to any structure member in a typedef’d struct located in a particular file causes a hard fault (unrecoverable). The faultmask register in my IDE has a value of "0" when it hits the Hard Fault Handler. This typedef is declared in the header file and an instance of it declared in the source file.
It’s a large struct, so thinking maybe some runaway memory issue creating a stack/heap issue, I created another in the same header file with only one member (a uint8_t, AKA byte). Same issue: attempting to assign the uint8_t a value of say, 32, results in a processor fault.
I use typedef’d structs throughout the code declared in the exact same way, a number of which are accessed before the one in question with no issues. The issue ONLY occurs in this one source file/header combo.
I’m struggling to think of something that would cause this or where to look next. Anyone have any thoughts?
Globals.h

typedef struct TestGlobWord_
{
    uint8_t GlobWord;
} TestGlobWord;

MyFile.c

TestGlobWord* GbobalWord = NULL;

void MyFunc(void)
{
    GbobalWord->GlobWord = 32;
}

EDIT: I have tried to more closely replicate my exact situation here.
Globals.h

typedef struct TestGlobWord_
{
    uint8_t GlobWord;
} TestGlobWord;

typedef struct Buffconfig_
{
    /// Size of provided RAM buffer.
    ssize_t     ramSize;
    void*       ramBuffer;
} Buffconfig_t;

MyFile.c

TestGlobWord* GbobalWord = NULL;

void MyFunc(Buffconfig_t *const config)
{
    if(config->ramBuffer != NULL)
    {
        GbobalWord = config->ramBuffer;

        GbobalWord->GlobWord = 32;
    }
} 


Is GlobalWord assigned somewhere? This particular snippet will be dereferencing a NULL pointer, so it's obviously not going to work.

@PMF: I am confusing myself with the struct. How do I need to assign GbobalWord?

I'm not sure what you really intend to do, in particular because you say you have already quite some code written and these problems would normally come up very early.
A declaration such as TestGlobWord* GlobalWord = NULL; (note the *!) declares a pointer to an instance of type TestGlobWord, but not assigning it anything (= NULL). Thus using that pointer will throw an error. To initialize the pointer to something, you can try:
void MyFunc(void)
{
    GlobalWord = new TestGlobWord();
    GlobalWord->GlobWord = 32;
}

or, to create a global instance directly, change the code to:
TestGlobWord GbobalWord; // NO star

void MyFunc(void)
{
    GbobalWord.GlobWord = 32; // Note that you now need to use the dot here to access the field
}


Hi, please see my edited example above. I was leaving out a key line which I believe should eliminate the NULL pointer dereference, but is not.

That doesn't say anything at all. What is config->ramBuffer pointing to? It could again be NULL.

Sorry, I miss-typed the line. The check is for a NULL pointer to ramBuffer. Corrected.
